# Use regex with for loop?

Tags: regex, bash, loops

I can run a while loop with regex successfully

```
$ cat while.sh
#!/bin/sh
arr=(a1c a2c a3c b4c)
i=0
while [[ ${arr[i]} =~ a(.)c ]]
do
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  ((i++))
done

$ ./while.sh
1
2
3
```

A for loop causes this error

```
$ cat for.sh
#!/bin/sh
arr=(a1c a2c a3c b4c)
for ((i=0; [[ ${arr[i]} =~ a(.)c ]]; i++))
do
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done

$ ./for.sh
./for.sh: line 3: ((: [[ a1c =~ a(.)c ]]: syntax error: operand expected (error
token is "[[ a1c =~ a(.)c ]]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your `for` loop construct is legal with regex. Double parenthesis are for [Arithmetic](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC34) expressions and that includes for loops. Regex matching is not arithmetic. I think if you were really set on using `for` for some reason, you would have to do something like:

```bsh
arr=(a1c a2c a3c b4c)

for val in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ $val =~ a(.)c ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi
done
```

Comment: Actually that syntax is valid for a for loop: `for (( i=0; i<5; i++ )); do echo $i; done`

Comment: I know, because `i<5` is an arithmetic expression. His regex in the middle is not. Edited my answer to make it more clear I meant it's not a valid construct the way he has it, not in general.

Comment: What he needs is the $? value from the  `[[ evaluation ]]`, not the result of it, but in his version the loop exits as soon as that evaluation is false.  Assuming he meant that to be the case.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like that, and it keeps trying to run whatever's in `$arg` as a command.

Answer (score 4):

To follow-up on my comment above, if you wanted to keep your formatting, more or less, this might do what you expected, because you need the return value of the evaluation as an expression in the for loop, not the output of it.

```
for ((i=0; `[[ ${arr[i]} =~ a(.)c ]] && echo -n 1`; i++)); do
    # do whatever 
done
```

Ugly, but worked for me, and should explain your error for you.  The back-ticks evaluate the expression then output either a '1' for true or nothing for false.  This leaves you the valid conditional for the loop in the middle.